# XML content inside PHP variable

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP variable which have xml content inside. If I `echo` the variable it is printing **1**. Why it is happening like this?

```
$xml =  "<?xml version='1.0'?><Item><qoh>".$quantity_to_update."</qoh></Item>";

echo $xml;
```

**OUTPUT**

> 1

Comment: Doesn't really look like XML that's inside your variable. That is a simple string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is printing 1 because you are using your tags between `<` and `>`. So, it is not showing in your html page. But may be present in the source of the HTML. Try this

```
echo htmlspecialchars($xml);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "$quantity_to_update" will have a value (I think it is 1). Please check your variable output.